# How to add multiple listeners in jQuery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, listeners

```
for (key in this.mybutton)
       button = this.mybutton[key]

       $(button).click(function() {
            console.log("click:" + button)
       });
```

The result is always the name of the last button. How can I add multiple listeners in jQuery/javascript or erase the javascript reference button to a string in the for.

thanks in advance

Comment: Using 'this' or maybe you need a cosure there. Could you provide a working sample as jsfiddle which show what are you looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a <s>closure</s> new scope :

```
for (key in this.mybutton)
   (function(button) {
       $(button).click(function() {
            console.log("click:" + button)
       });
   })(this.mybutton[key]);
}
```

or just use `this`:

```
$(button).click(function() {
    console.log("click:" + this)
});
```

Concatenating a DOM element and a string in the console log doesn't seem like a very good idea ?

Comment: No, not a closure (the event handler *is already* a closure). You need to create a new *scope*. [See my comments here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517111/javascript-binding-click-handller-inside-a-loop/17517127#comment25470265_17517127) for a more extensive explanation (this is just regarding the first snippet, of course the second one is a much better solution anyway).

Comment: @FelixKling - thanks, that's a good explanation, and even if I understood why it worked, I've never really thought about the fact that any function will create a closure, and as such the closure isn't the reason it works, passing the parameter to keep it constant within the __new scope__ is!

Comment: thanks,exactly what i want. The concatenation was just to give an simple example of my problem, it's doesn't have a real utility :p